# Behaviors in UWP (Event trigger command error

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, blend, uwp-xaml

**SCENERIO:**

I have a custom control where the control template has a grid. I want to add a behavior to the grid tapped event.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:**

I have installed the Nuget package for managed UWP behaviors

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed
```

In the custom control's resource dictionary, I have the following xml namespaces referenced along with other necessary namespaces

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

Then in the custom control, in the grid block, I have the following

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
       <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CustomCommand}"/>
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
 </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

**ISSUES:**

The `core:InvokeCommandAction` has the blue squiggly line with this error

> The type EventTriggerBehavior does not 
>   support direct content

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE:**

> Create a custom control. Nothing special,maybe just a grid. Add the EventTriggerBehavior as shown above to the grid. Use the created control on a page in your application

This right here is where I'm stuck at. I've done a lot of Google searches and just can't find a way out of this error. 
Any help and code correction will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The core:InvokeCommandAction has the blue squiggly line with this error
>
> The type EventTriggerBehavior does not support direct content

I made a basic demo and reproduced this problem. It is a XAML Designer issue. After building the project, this error is gone. So please make sure your codes are correct and go ahead build your project.

Comment: when I do a clean+build the squiggly vanishes but the custom control has an H RESULT e_fail error. So please can you try creating a custom control, maybe just a grid. And adding the behavior to it then applying the control to a page to see if you can reproduce the issue there. Maybe I should update my question wirh that

Comment: I did,I created a Templated Control, added a grid in the xaml with EventTrigger inside. And I used it in the main page. but I didn't have the error. Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Okay, I will update the question when I get home which will be in a couple of hours

Comment: I can confirm that after I restarted the project (copied the files from the old project to a new one and deleted the old one), your answer works. So I'm accepting your answer as it solves the issue