# Binding Ui-Events to Commands in UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I would like to bind any UI-Event directly to a command in my ViewModel.
Is there a way to do that in **UWP**?

I'm using the UWP Community Toolkit and would like to bind the Hamburger-Menu-Item-Click to an command.

Thanks
Tobias

Comment: yes, thank you! that is what I needed!

Answer (score 8):

Ok I found the solution for that.
You can find it here: [Behaviors in UWP (Event trigger command error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389984/behaviors-in-uwp-event-trigger-command-error)

I will repeat my steps here:

1 - Install Package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed
```

2 - Include references to you view

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

3- Add the command to your ViewModel

```
        public DelegateCommand MenuItemCommand { get; set; }

        public void InitCommands()
        {
            MenuItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(MenuItemClicked);                            
        }

        private void MenuItemClicked()
        {
            //do something when clicked
        }
```

4 - Bind the Click-Event of the menuitem to the command in the view (see the i:...-tag)

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="HamburgerMenuControl"
                            PaneBackground="Black"
                            Foreground="White"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"
                            OptionsItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
                            OptionsItemsSource="{Binding MenuOptionItems}"
                            >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MenuItemCommand}"></core:InvokeCommandAction>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu>
</Grid>
```

when I know click the menu-item it