# why does x:Bind expect a static method to bind to?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, xbind

I have a UWP MVVM application where I bind, amongst others, the following property to a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`:

```
public List<ComboBoxValues> ListValues { get; set; } = new List<ComboBoxValues>();
```

XAML:

```
xmlns:local="using:MyProject.ViewModels"
    <controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="myHeader"
        Binding="{Binding theSelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind local:PageVM.ListValues, Mode=OneWay}"
        DisplayMemberPath="theValueOptions"/>
```

I use dependency injection, using Autofac to generate an instance of my viewModels when needed:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.RegisterType<PageVM>().AsSelf();
```

I get the error:  `Static method 'ListValues' not found in type 'PageVM'.` I have tried googling it, and the only results that I find is that it should not be that easy to bind to a static property etc.

Why is x:bind expecting a static method? I don't want to use static properties/methods.

EDIT:

The `DataContext` of pages are also set using a NavigationService and ViewModelBinder with code, though NOT the code-behind page. Autofac, the IoC manages the instances of those, the NavigationService and the ViewModelBinder. Thus, I do not know how to link the XAML to those instances to use x:Bind?

I do not want to use code behind, as I am trying to strictly stick to MVVM.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah so the problem is the below line:

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind local:PageVM.ListValues, Mode=OneWay}"
```

What you're doing with this code is, telling the xaml `BindingEngine` to look for a class called `PageVM` under the `xmlns:local` and then look for a field called `ListValues`. Now since we don't have an instance of the `PageVM` (as per the above line), it's considering `ListValues` as `static` and is trying to find it.

Generally to bind to a `ViewModel`, you set the `DataContext` of the `Page` or `UserControl`. You can do so like:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:PageVM x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

if you're using a `UserControl` the above would look like:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:PageVM x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

and now use it in `xaml` code like below:

```
<controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="myHeader"
    Binding="{Binding theSelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ListValues, Mode=OneWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="theValueOptions"/>
```

*Notice the `x:Name="ViewModel"`, as part of the DataContext. This would allow you to reference your `ViewModel` via the `codebehind` too.*

### Edit After comments

Alternatively, if you cannot have a public parameterless constructor then I suggest you use the codebehind to create an instance of the ViewModel like below:

```
public PageVM ViewModel => this.DataContext as PageVM;
```

*There is no clause that performs a null check on the above property since from the comments, the data context is being set via a dependency injection framework*

and then use it the same way in your xaml code:

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ListValues, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Iam.Carrot, when setting the DataContext in XAML, I get the error that it wants the ViewModel to have an "accessible constructor", "it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter". I need to pass interface instances via DI to the constructor. Also, I should have mentioned, the DataContext is set with a NavigationService and ViewModelBinder "via DI containerBuilder". Please let me know which code you would like to see, if you do need to see more?

Comment: hi @iam.Carrot, please see my edit and additional information in the question

Comment: if the `datacontext` is also set using another `service` then simply use `Binding` instead of `x:bind`. To get a reference of the `DataContext` to use it in the code behind just use the `ViewModel` property I defined above in the codebehind and remove the `if (this.DataContext == null)` clause

Comment: I can't use Binding, since I want to bind the ItemsSource of a DataGridComboBoxColumn within a DataGrid, that uses Binding - I have to use x:Bind otherwise the column goes to look within the Grid's binding. It Works however with x:bind (though I'm not sure if I am violating the MVVM rules of being loosely coupled). But, when using it within <interactcore:InvokeCommandAction>, it then wants to search for ViewModel within 'DataTemplate'! Should I post a new question?

Comment: So a way would be to use the `ViewModel` property defined in the codebehind, like I have done above. I've modified the answer as well.

Comment: I am using the `ViewModel` property as you showed:  `Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ToggleSwitchToggled_Command}"`, however I then get the error message: `Invalid binding path... : Property ViewModel not found on type DataTemplate`

Comment: Have you defined the `ViewModel` in the `codebehind` or in `xaml`?

Comment: in `codebehind`, in Page.xaml.cs.   The code file linked to the xaml page.

Comment: strange, can you post up a sample on github *(where I can reproduce the issue)*? I might need more information to figure out.

Comment: I should have mentioned, the `Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ToggleSwitchToggled_Command}"` is within a `<interact:Interaction.Behaviours>` , as in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304970/binding-ui-events-to-commands-in-uwp)  Does that give more insight?  if not, I can post a sample on github

Comment: Yeah let's just post up a sample on github.

Comment: see the sample [here](https://github.com/derMaaster/GitExamples.git), thanks for the help

Comment: great! thanks for sharing it. I'll look into it later today/tomorrow

Comment: hi @iam.Carrot, have you had a chance to look at it?

Comment: Hey thanks for a reminder, I'll look at it today.

Comment: @Allstar I've added the explanations as part of an Issue.